# Stop blender creating a copy of a material when copy and pasting an object

Tags: materials

Lets say I have a cube with a material called red which just has a red color and I copy and paste that cube. I have 2 cubes and 2 different materials, the one is called " red.001 " and the original one is just " red ".

I usually go to the blender file in the outliner and remove all the unnecessary copies of the material, since I only need one red for all cubes.

While this is not a big problem with very small projects. It can become annoying when I copy a cube 100 times and end up getting 99 copies of the original material, so I have to manually delete all those 99 material copies.

Is it possible with a button or a switch or setting to tell blender to stop doing this? To not copy a material when copying an object with the original material? To just assign the original material to the pasted copy?

It would speed things and up and reduce the total amount of clicks needed. Optimizing workflows in blender is very important.

Comment: Can't you just use Shift-D to duplicate the object rather than copy and paste? That way the original material is used on the duplicate.

Comment: @JohnEason I do that when this is my intention, sometimes I use the same material for different objects that have different UVs and everything that can't be linked this way. For those cases, this won't work.

Comment: @John Eason Oh yes you're right, it seems to be the problem here

Answer (score 0):

Edit: My bad, my solution is for <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, but you're using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.

By default in the *Preferences > Editing > Objects > Duplicate Data, Material* should be disabled, disable it:

[image]

Comment: I just disabled it and it still happens :(

Comment: How do you duplicate objects? Does it still duplicate materials when starting from a new fresh scene?

Comment: @L0Lock He uses Ctrl C Ctrl V, not Shift D, not sure why though